# php curl translation of python request

Tags: php, curl

I have a code written in python to call an API and download info. It works perfect on python with this simple code:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://xxx/auth/getToken'
payload = {"X-Username":"myusername","X-Password":"mypassword"}
headers = {"X-Username":"myusername","X-Password":"mypassword"}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
token = r.headers['X-Auth-Token']
print(token)
```

This works perfect. But, when i translate this to PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "http://xxx/auth/getToken";
$ch_header = array('X-Username' => 'myusername', 'X-Password' => 'mypassword');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $ch_header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ch_header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
$server_output = (curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

I get an unauthorized response. is the translation correct? any obvious mistake that i'm missing?

Comment: Try to `json_encode`the array. https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

i get it. the problem was on the array.

```
$ch_header = array('X-Username' => 'myusername', 'X-Password' => 'mypassword');
```

with this structure it worked out.

```
$ch_header = array('X-Username:myusername', 'X-Password:mypassword');
```